# Prove that matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} x & x \\ x & x \end{pmatrix}$ are a group under matrix multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

G is the set of matrices of the form $G=$$\begin{pmatrix} x & x \\ x & x \end{pmatrix}$.
So for this set to be a group I know it needs to be:

- Closed under matrix multiplication
- The Associative Property holds
- Contains an Identity Element
- Every element needs to have an inverse

So the form of the matrices is such that all the elements are the same but not 0. How do I go about proving these?

Working through this problem, I seem to have hit a contradiction. Since G is a subgroup of the bigger $2x2$ nonsingular matrices group why does G not have the same identity element as its parent group? Namely \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}

Isn't the subgroup supposed to have the same identity element as its parent group?

Comment: For starters, what do you expect the identity element to look like?

Comment: But these matrices are not invertible.

Comment: @user99680 Since the identity of the group is NOT the identity matrix, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @N.S: How do you know how multiplication is defined?

Comment: @user99680 Because, unless otherwise specified in the exercise, multiplication of matrices is the standard multiplication of matrices... And if it is not standard, what do you mean by invertible? ;)

Comment: @N.S: But under the standard multiplication, these matrices are not invertible.Ah, maybe there is an identity for the subgroup that is not the same as the identity for the group?

Comment: @user99680 Yes, but it doesn't matter. It only shows it is not a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb R)$. But there are groups of non-invertible matrices. It simply means that the identity of the group is not the identity matrix.... A simpler example is the following: matrices of the type $\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ with $a \neq 0$ are a group under multiplication, even if they are not invertible. The identity in this case is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and the inverse is $\begin{bmatrix} \frac1{a} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$...And when you multiply these matrices

Comment: @N.S: Good call.

Comment: ... you basically multiply the numbers in the first position, the rest of the matrix is irrelevant... Note that the invertibility of the matrix means $A A^{-1}=I_n$, while the inverse in the group means something else : $AB=E$, where $E$ is sometimes a different matrix. Just because we call them identity and inverse element, it doesn't mean they are the identity matrix and inverse matrix...

Comment: The matrices don't need to be invertible. They just need to be invertible on any subspace they ever touch. $x[1,1]^T[1,1]$ is only non-invertible on $[1,1]^T[1,1]$ if $x=0$.

Comment: I have learned so much from this question.

Answer (score 11):

**Hint**

1) What is $\begin{bmatrix} x & x \\ x & x \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y & y \\ y & y \end{bmatrix}$?

2) The multiplication of matrices is associative.

3) When you are looking for the identity you want

$$\begin{bmatrix} x & x \\ x & x \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} e & e \\ e & e \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x & x \\ x & x \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, do the multiplication on the left, what do you get?

4) With the $e$ from $3)$ solve

$$\begin{bmatrix} x & x \\ x & x \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y & y \\ y & y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} e & e \\ e & e \end{bmatrix}$$

for $y$. Again, all you need to do is doing the multiplication...

**P.S.** In order for this to be a group, you need $x \neq 0$.

**P.P.S** Since $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=2\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, you can prove that

$$F: \mathbb R \backslash\{0 \} \to G$$
$$F(x) =\frac{x}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

is a bijection and it preserves multiplications. Since $\mathbb R \backslash\{0 \}$ is a group it follows that G must also be a group and $F$ is an isomorphism... But this is probably beyond what you covered so far...

Comment: 1.  $\begin{matrix}
  2xy & 2xy \\
  2xy & 2xy
 \end{matrix}$


2. Yup thats the easy one.

3. You did the multiplication on the left? Multiplying x by the identity element will give you x, like you have above..

Comment: @RoyM. The multiplication on the left is $\begin{bmatrix}
  2xe & 2xe \\
  2xe & 2xe
 \end{bmatrix}$. Now for which value of $e$ do you get:$$\begin{bmatrix}
  2xe & 2xe \\
  2xe & 2xe
 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
  x & x \\
  x & x
 \end{bmatrix} \, ? ;)$$

Comment: Are you talking about your first bullet? \begin{bmatrix} x & x \\ x & x \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y & y \\ y & y \end{bmatrix}

For which value of $e$ do I get what? I am sorry I am not following!

Comment: @RoyM. I am speaking about $3$. Keep in mind that identity in a group of matrices doesn't necessarily mean identity matrix ;)

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying. And for your first comment, $e=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @RoyM. Exactly... And now when you solve for the inverse, you have $\begin{bmatrix}
  2xy & 2xy \\
  2xy & 2xy
 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{matrix}
  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
 \end{matrix}$. Thus $y=\frac{1}{4x}$...